# What is the difference between async.waterfall and async.series

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, node-async

The nodejs async module: https://github.com/caolan/async provides 2 similar methods, `async.waterfall` and `async.series`.

What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 174, accepted):

It appears that `async.waterfall` allows each function to pass its results on to the next function, while `async.series` passes all results to the final callback. At a higher level, `async.waterfall` would be for a data pipeline ("given 2, multiply it by 3, add 2, and divide by 17"), while `async.series` would be for discrete tasks that must be performed in order, but are otherwise separate.

Comment: Is it possible for either of these two functions to return a value? I've read that it's possible, but I can't find relevant information anywhere in the documentation.

Comment: @AndersonGreen: Nope. Looking at the library source, neither `waterfall` nor `series` returns a value. It's expected that whatever the result is will be used in the optional callback parameter.

Comment: The above answer may be correct back to 2012, but the correct one is the same as the next, which is: series() as it's named that ALL results as a series passed to the Final callback, and waterfall is the LAST result passed to the Final callback. See [Mozilla Developer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/Displaying_data)

Answer (score 53):

Both functions pass the return value, of every function to the next, then when done will call the main callback, passing its error, if an error happens.

The difference is that `async.series()`, once the series have finished, will pass all the results to the main callback. `async.waterfall()` will pass to the main callback only the result of the last function called.

Comment: This should be the answer ;-)

Comment: @Mario "Both functions pass the callback of the previous function" OR "Both functions pass the result of the previous function" ?

Comment: @user1451111, Result, lol... I am sure I had written that the first time though...

Answer (score 27):

[`async.waterfall()`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CR0P3.png) is dealing with an `action that relies on the previous outcome`.

[`async.series()`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZVH6.png) is dealing with an action that wants to `see all the result  at the end`

Comment: Awesomely created images. Did you create them yourself or got them somewhere else?

Comment: you should put the pictures in the answer, people will probably miss them o/w

Answer (score 2):

I consider async.waterfall to be harmful, because it's hard to refactor once written and also error-prone since if you supply more arguments, other functions much change the signature.

I highly recommend `async.autoInject` as a great alternative, to async.waterfall.
https://caolan.github.io/async/autoInject.js.html

If you do choose to use async.waterfall, I recommend storing everything in one object, so your functions don't have to change length/signatures, like so:

**warning: this is a bad pattern**

```
async.waterfall([
  cb => {
    cb(null, "one", "two");
  },
  (one, two, cb) => {
    cb(null, 1, 2, 3, 4);
  },
  (one,two,three,four,cb) => {
     // ...
  }
])
```

don't do it the above way. This is **a much better pattern** to use:

```
async.waterfall([
  cb => {
    cb(null, {one:"one", two:"two"});
  },
  (v, cb) => {
    cb(null, [1, 2, 3, 4]);
  },
  (v,cb) => {
     // ...
  }
])
```

that way you won't pull your hair out trying to make sure the function arguments have the right length. The first function only accepts one arg - callback. All the remaining ones should accept two arguments - a value and callback. Stick to the pattern and you will remain sane!